# Fetch data from Hierarchical Data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I store multi level category. The table look like this:

### Categories Table

```
+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
| category_id | category_name | parent_category_id |
+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
|           1 | Clothing      | NULL               |
|           2 | Footwear      | NULL               |
|           3 | Men           | 1                  |
|           4 | Women         | 1                  |
|           5 | Shirts        | 3                  |
|           6 | T-Shirts      | 3                  |
|           7 | Jeans         | 3                  |
+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

### company_category_mapping Table

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
| cmp_cat_id | company_id | category_id |
+------------+------------+-------------+
|          1 |          7 |           5 |
|          2 |          7 |           6 |
|          3 |          7 |           7 |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

I want to fetch all category, sub-category, sub-sub-category from category table with respect of company_id. I am confused how do this. can i create a new table for store company category?

I want to display output in drop-down.
I have three drop-down one is main category dropdown, second is sub-category drop-down and third is sub-sub-category drop-down. Drop-down is fill companies wise i.e different company has different category.

Output display screen.

[image: This is my output display category]

Sorry for my English.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: have you tried any thing??

Comment: Can you put the out put that you expect? use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Why dont you create three loops.

First will show all main category where parent category is null and companyid is given .

and second loop will be depending on the result of first loop categoryids.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place where you can post your code, and ask people to write code for you. You'll have to try something, and show what you're getting stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
  SELECT c1.`category_name` as `category` , c2.`category_name` as `sub-category`, c3.`category_name` as `sub-sub-category` FROM `categories` as c1
    LEFT JOIN `categories` as c2 ON c1.`category_id`=c2.`parent_category_id`
    LEFT JOIN `categories` as c3 ON c2.`category_id`=c3.`parent_category_id`
    where c1.`parent_category_id` IS NULL
```

**With respect of company_id**

```
SELECT cm.`company_id`, c1.`category_name` as `category` , c2.`category_name` as `sub-category`, c3.`category_name` as `sub-sub-category` FROM `categories` as c1
LEFT JOIN `categories` as c2 ON c1.`category_id`=c2.`parent_category_id`
LEFT JOIN `categories` as c3 ON c2.`category_id`=c3.`parent_category_id`
INNER JOIN `company_category_mapping` as cm ON cm.`category_id`=c3.`category_id`
    where c1.`parent_category_id` IS NULL
```

If you need to get data for specific company_id.

**Ex : company_id =7**

```
SELECT cm.`company_id`, c1.`category_name` as `category` , c2.`category_name` as `sub-category`, c3.`category_name` as `sub-sub-category` FROM `categories` as c1
    LEFT JOIN `categories` as c2 ON c1.`category_id`=c2.`parent_category_id`
    LEFT JOIN `categories` as c3 ON c2.`category_id`=c3.`parent_category_id`
    INNER JOIN `company_category_mapping` as cm ON cm.`category_id`=c3.`category_id` AND cm.`company_id`=7
        where c1.`parent_category_id` IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks u for reply. But I want to display category with respect of company_id.

Comment: Thank a lot of u. Its works for me. @KTAnj. One changes in this code is  parent_category_name should be parent_category_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

> **i am using mysqli to avoid problems and hacking**

```
$results = $mysqli->query( "SQL
SELECT *
FROM `categories` as c1
LEFT JOIN `categories` as c2 ON c1.`category_id`=c2.`parent_category_name`
LEFT JOIN `categories` as c3 ON c2.`category_id`=c3.`parent_category_name`
where c1.`parent_category_name` IS NULL");echo 'Results is: ' . $result;
```